# Get entries where relation matches or is empty

Tags: relations

I have a channel section (`tickets`) where each entry has a `members` field. The `members` field can either be empty (making the entry 'public') or specific members can be added (making it 'private', to only the selected users).

I want to get a list of all the entries within the section where the `members` field is *either* empty or the `currentMember` has been added to the list, e.g. a member should see both public entries **and** private entries they have been added to.

I'm using the following to get all private entries for the currentMember, but I can't figure out how to make it include the public ones as well.

```
{% set tickets = craft.entries.section('tickets').relatedTo({
    targetElement: currentMember,
    field: 'members'
}) %}
```

Comment: Man, that's exactly what I would need too. Any progress on this?

Comment: Any progress on this? I have the exact same problem to solve...

Comment: I've submitted a bug report on this. This is something that should work out of the box in Craft without building two separate queries as others suggested. I would be shocked if they say it's not a bug and it's not possible. https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/7256

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that comes across this. Craft CMS has added this as a feature for next release.
https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/7256#issuecomment-744644568