# Advanced search entries relatedTo category and unrelated to any category

Tags: categories, relatedto

I know the long-form method for achieving my goal, but I'm hitting a wall in trying to keep the conditionals down.

Is it possible to search for entries related to a specific category field **AND** search for entries with no category selection for that same field?

Right now, I can only do the first part. Here's a snippet of a much larger query.

```
{# get all categories within specific category groups #}
{% set skillsOptions = craft.categories.group('skillsCategories') %}
{% set durationOptions = craft.categories.group('durationCategories') %}

{# working: find all entries with any category selected #}
{# not working: also find all entries with no category selected #}
{% set opportunities = craft.entries.section('opportunities').relatedTo('and',
    {
        targetElement: ['or', skillsOptions],
        field: 'skills'
    },
    {
        targetElement: ['or', durationOptions],
        field: 'duration'
    }
%}
```

Comment: Similar question I didn't see before: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12391/get-entries-where-relation-matches-or-is-empty

Comment: I've decided to require the category fields and added an "undefined" option that won't show in our filters. That does the trick.